# Facebook SDK Deferred deeplinks not working in iOS 14

Tags: ios, deep-linking, facebook-ios-sdk, ios14

My existing and new apps are not able to handle deferred deeplinks on iOS 14. This was not happening until I updated to iOS 14.

**Steps**:

1. Use Deep link tester from App ads helper and send a deferred deep link.
2. Tap the notification and get redirected to the correct AppStore app page
3. Build and run the project from Xcode
4. `AppLinkUtility.fetchDeferredAppLink` is called, but `url` and `error` are always nil.

Answer (score 5):

I have some bad news for you.
Apple requires user opt-in to share IDFA on iOS 14 and therefore your deferred deeplinking won't be working unless you have gotten permission by the user first.

Comment: Woah. Thanks for the info, that's big. So all apps that use deferred deep linking will have to just drop it? No workaround/other functionality like this is going to be possible at all?